# Filter Database through a Form in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a set of database on excel with multiple forms in order to add data. I have put a Switch Board in order to limit the navigation around the databases, to force people to only access the parts they are meant to.

I am attempting to implement a drop down combo box at the top of the page to select which location the user is at, and therefore filter the databases to only allow data entry and searches for the selected location, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please elaborate a bit more what you are trying to achieve? I am a bite stuck to be honest.

1. What do you mean with "location".
2. When you speak of "databases", do you mean tables or in fact (I suppose external, linked) databases?
3. "a set of database on excel", I suppose you mean access?!

Anyway, let me try to shed some light on your issue.
Limiting user access is usually defined by limiting the access to forms.
Using buttons for navigation, this can easily be achieved by calling:

```
Private Sub Testbutton_Click()
  If Test_Condition = TRUE Then
   DoCmd.OpenForm "test_form"
  Else
   DoCmd.OpenForm "test_form", , , ,acFormReadOnly
  End If
End Sub
```

Or - which might suite your "locations" a bit better

```
Private Sub Testbutton_Click()
  Select Case Me.Location
    Case 1,3,6,8
      DoCmd.OpenForm "test_form"
    Case 2,4,5,7
      DoCmd.OpenForm "test_form", , , ,acFormReadOnly
    Case Else
      MsgBox "You can't access the selected form using that location"
  End If
End Sub
```

Here, for the selected location 1, 3, 6, and 8, the form is opened in the standard view with all rights to add and edit entries.
For the selected location 2, 4, 5, and 7, access will open the form in ReadOnly-View.
For all other locations, it will prompt a message.